# table_calendar package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, display, table-calendar

I have added Table_Calendar package into my Flutter project. (table calendar > https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar)
I just want to use if for basic date actions but wanted to display badges for each day by the event count in that day. Like I figured out in below image;

[image]

I just use the basic example one to display the base calendar, navigate between dates. But need to add that colorful badges with numbers by the events of each day. Showing the events in a modal sheet, (when the user taps on a date) was already completed.

**Honestly, I could not find the sub-file that populating the calendar's visible dates, and therefore I could not update that code part.**

Is there anyone who has experienced with that?

Thank you